# How do I stop my :after content from blocking my anchor?

Tags: html, css

I've made a simple Fiddle to demonstrate my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/JTqww/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#">
            <img SRC="http://www.mikesfreegifs.com/main4/halloween/comehere.gif"/>
            <span class="desc">Description</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

.button a {
    background:green;
    float:left;
    z-index:-1;
}

img {
    display:inline-block;
}

.desc{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
.button:after {
    position:   absolute; 
    top:        10%;
    left:       10%; 
    content:"I destroy your anchor";
    color:red;
    position:   absolute; 
    width:      50%;
    height:     50%;


    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

As you can see, I've made a button with an overlaid glass reflection effect, on top of an image. I wanted the image and the description below to all be wrapped in an anchor tag (which they are but the :after content seems to block the anchor). If you move the mouse outside of the glossy white area, it will interact with the anchor but inside that area of white gloss it will not.

I've tried floating the anchor and changing the z-index but the content placed :after the button (the 'gloss') seems to stop the anchor from receiving mouse-overs and click events.

Anyone know how to fix this? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `:after` content is not part of the anchor it won't be clickable so you cannot place it over the top of your anchor and then expect to be able to click your anchor

now if you changed `.before:after` to `.desc:after` your link will be clickable:

http://jsfiddle.net/JTqww/2/

you'll just have to mess with the styles to get it to line up again

Comment: Actually, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

I workaround with your code, so that it looks nice.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JTqww/8/)

To make the click work on the added description too, just give `:after` to `a` or `span` tag instead of the class `.button`.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JTqww/12/)

Comment: This probably wants to be .button a:after rather than on all anchors, but otherwise works well.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pete states, your generated content is not part of your anchor, so it won't act as such. The simplest fix is just to remove your `div.button` altogether, and apply that class directly to your `a`:

```
    <a href="#" class="button">
        <img SRC="http://www.mikesfreegifs.com/main4/halloween/comehere.gif"/>
        <span class="desc">Description</span>
    </a>
```

The generated content itself is part of the anchor and so is clickable. Your initial CSS needs some tidying up as well. The `button` class, whatever it's applied to, needs to have `position: relative` so that it creates a new positioning context. The overlay will then sit correctly - see [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/DVEt3/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can give direct `div`

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.mikesfreegifs.com/main4/halloween/comehere.gif"/>
        <div class="overlay">I destroy your anchor</div>
        <span class="desc">Description</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JTqww/6/)**